# How do you transfer a directory with multiple sub-directories over ftp?

Tags: macos, ftp, directory

I'm a novice user trying to figure out how to transfer a 48 Gb directory (from the Mac Terminal command line) that contains multiple sub-directories, which themselves contain multiple directories, ... I'd like to not have to confirm the transfer of each sub-directory with a 'y/n' prompt.

Comment: Why "off-topic"?  It's a useful question.  Programmers need to ftp subdirectories, too.

Answer (score 12):

Use `mput *` or `mget *`. When asked for confirmation, type `a` instead of `y`. This is the same as answering `y` for every single file for one command.

You can also change the prompting behavior using the `prompt` command.

You will find more information in the man page. In Terminal type: `man ftp`

Answer (score 7):

ftp -i turns off prompts. mget * gets all the files.

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7000]
    Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    C:\so>ftp -i **hostname**
    Connected to hostname.
    220 Microsoft FTP Service
    User (hostname:(none)): **username**
    331 Password required for username.
    Password:
    230 User username logged in.
    ftp> **cd logs**
    250 CWD command successful.
    ftp> **ls**
    200 PORT command successful.
    150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.
    meetmap.com
    226 Transfer complete.
    ftp: 115 bytes received in 0.01Seconds 11.50Kbytes/sec.
    ftp> mget *
    200 Type set to A.
    200 PORT command successful.
    150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for meetmap.com/ex090131.log
        (5490 bytes).

    226 Transfer complete.
    ... (bunch more files)
    ftp> **quit**
    221

    C:\so>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question was to FTP Directory and not Files; and as far aswhat I know(am not at all a expert) you cant FTP directories using mget/mput save for using tar files(under unix ie.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use scp to transfer entire directories from the shell prompt. For example:

MyMachine$ scp -r FromMachine:[Directory Path] [Destination Path]

This copies the entire directory and its contents to the destination path on MyMachine. Please see "man scp" for more information.

Users IMHO should be using sftp and ssh as FTP sends passwords as clear text.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most efficient is to tar compress it and sftp and untar it on the other end.
Here are the steps :

1. Go to terminal and cd to the directory you want to move.
2. tar -zcvf yourFolder.tar.gz youFolder/
3. then sftp and cd to the directory and do mget or mput yourFolder.tar.gz
4. tar -zxvf yourFolder.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

ncftp should to be able to recursively get files.
Alternatively, use any of infinite graphical drag and drop ftp clients.

Answer (score 0):

This worked quite well for me:

$ `ncftp gnu.ftp.org`

$ `ncftp /old-gnu/Manuals > get -R -T sharutils`